# How does php substr deal with two offset values?

Tags: php, string, trim, substr

Consider the following:

```
echo substr("abcdefgh", 1, -1);
// outputs bcdefg  
echo substr("abcdefgh", 2, -2);
// outputs cdef
```

Seems like `substr` is taking first numeric parameter as offset from start of the string and the second parameter as another offset from the end of the string.

I went through the official docs https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php They don't mention that there can be two offsets. They rather expect the second numeric parameter to be the `length`.

So, does `substr` take the second numeric argument as a second offset from the end when it is negative?

---

**Edit:** To further add to the question, as discussed in the comments, the docs mention:

> If $length is given and is negative, then that many characters will be omitted from the end of string **(after the start position has been calculated when a offset is negative)**.

This part is confusing, because It says *after the start position has been calculated when a offset is negative*. If we take the second numeric argument as length, then there is no offset which is negative.

Comment: Well, the documentation you linked is crystal clear: "If `$length` is given and is negative, then that many characters will be omitted from the end of string (after the start position has been calculated when a offset is negative)."

Comment: Second param would be still length even if it's negative. So, -3 is the same as strlen() - 3

Comment: @Blackhole That is confusing to me. It says _after the start position has been calculated when a offset is negative)._ If we take the second numeric argument as _length_, then there is no _offset_ which is negative.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. You can safely ignore the sentence in parenthesis, it does not give any useful information (in some translations of this documentation page, it's not even there).

Comment: If you think this is confusing, feel free to open a pull request for the documentation to enhance it

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear. If someone could ask what is not clear, I can explain that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mustn't have read far enough into the description!

> If length is given and is negative, then that many characters will be
> omitted from the end of string...

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

---

Update based on edited question:

> after the start position has been calculated when a offset is negative

This is simply clarifying that it will calculate the start position using the `offset` parameter first, then the `length` parameter second, rather than vice versa as that would give you differing results.

Consider this:

```
php > echo substr("phpisfun", -5, -2);
isf
```

If you were to modify this string using the `length` parameter first, followed by the `offset`, you would get the string "hpisf" instead.

It might seem like a confusing sentence at first but it's bringing clarity to the execution order in this particular instance.

Comment: ...and... in cases like `substr("abcdefgh", 2, -2);` the order of execution  doesn't matter, whether we use `offset` first or `length` first.

Comment: @user31782 Yes that's correct. Only `when a offset is negative`.